# What is Telepathy Indicator Service and can I remove it?

Tags: startup-applications, telepathy

What is telepathy-indicator? And what does it do? All I can find is that it's a "Desktop service to integrate Telepathy with the messaging menu" which, I'm afraid, means nothing to me. Can I remove it safely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Empathy (the Instant Messaging client) uses Telepathy for protocol support.

The telepathy-indicator is just the (sub-)indicator in the messaging indicator.